# How can I solve " cuda 2D conv problem "?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

this is my code , but predict funtion not work

Error:
[image: output error]

```
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
from keras.utils.vis_utils import plot_model
#Keras will download the weight files from the Internet and store them in the ~/.keras/models directory.
model = VGG16()

from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input
# load an image from file
image = load_img('output.png', target_size=(224, 224))

# convert the image pixels to a numpy array
image = img_to_array(image)
# reshape data for the model
image = image.reshape((1, image.shape[0], image.shape[1], image.shape[2]))

# prepare the image for the VGG model
image = preprocess_input(image)


from keras.applications.vgg16 import decode_predictions
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
# predict the probability across all output classes
yhat = model.predict(image)
# convert the probabilities to class labels
label = decode_predictions(yhat)
# retrieve the most likely result, e.g. highest probability
label = label[0][0]
# print the classification
print('%s (%.2f%%)' % (label[1], label[2]*100))
img = Image.open('output.png')
plt.imshow(img)
```

whast should I do ??
wekfjeojocwjcopjcoekcopejcpoekcpwekcpejoejocijewjwrjwihujviruhviuhr

Comment: You may want to paste your error code as plain text (instead of a screenshot) to make it easier for people to help you.

Answer (score 0):

The error is that it failed to the the convolution algorithm. Not sure of all the things that can cause this error but when I get that error it is because I have more than one instance of python running that is using tensorflow. So in your jupyter notebook disable the kernel for all python open notebooks except for the notebook you want to run.